# UART cannot RX GPS NMEA sentences

Tags: c, gps, msp430, uart

My UART is configured for 4800baud rate, Well I am not able to RX the NMEA sentences(GPS eval board) using the UART code pasted below. Individually GPS+Terminal and UART+Terminal is working fine . But GPS+UART , I am never able to RX any sentences
GPS default buad rate is 4800

Any idea where I am going wrong with UART???

```
/**
 * uart default at 4800 ACLK= 32.768KHz
 * @4800 bps
 */

  void UART_default(void){  
  P3SEL = BIT3+BIT4;                         
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_1;                     
  UCA0BR0 = 0x06;                           
  UCA0BR1 = 0x00;                           
  UCA0MCTL |= UCBRS_6+UCBRF_0;              
  UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     
  UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;                         
}

#pragma vector=USCI_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A0_ISR(void)
{
  volatile char byte;
    switch(__even_in_range(UCA0IV,4))
  {
  case 0:break;                             // Vector 0 - no interrupt
  case 2:               
    byte=  UCA0RXBUF;
    if (byte == '\r') { 
            push_char(byte);                    // At end of Data transmission
            ptr = 0;
        }
    else{                       
            push_char(byte);  
                ptr++;  
        }
    break;  
  case 4:break;                                        
  default: break;   
  }     
}
```

Comment: Some questions to narrow down where the problem might lie: have you verified the GPS is sending data? Does a logic analyzer on the RX line see valid 4800bps data?  Can you receive data polling the UART instead of using an interrupt?

Comment: I'd also ask how do you know you are not receiving the lines - how have you tested that and how are you trying to process the lines? What does push_char() do and how is ptr used in the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace the GPS by a PC with a USB <-> UART converter ?
This could validate the baudrate setup in your MSP430 as well as the ability to receive something.